# Submitting Forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i have multiple forms on a page generated dynamically.  Im assigning a unique id to each form example form1, form2, form3 etc.  Each form contains a hidden field one with name of id and next with name of action.

im doing an `onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();"` or whatever form id i want submitted. The problem is it isnt passing the correct hidden field id number.  In FF4 it passes the last forms id val and in safari its passing the first id val?

Whats am i doing wrong? Probably dumb and simple but im not seeing it.

Comment: what about accepting some previous answers AND adding some HTML code?

Comment: @ITroubs, What if he asked tough questions and never got a correct answer?  Doing that encourages wrong answer confirmations and creating bad information to future searchers.

Comment: Hello, what happens if you submit a form on this way: documents.forms['form1'].submit() ? Will you get the same result?

Comment: OK, i dont know what the answer is but i found how to avoid it.  It wasnt working where the link was on a map item.  I have avoided a map on an image and done it as an <a> and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onClick = document.form1.submit();

Answer (score 0):

"multiple forms"? So you have something like

```
<form ...>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" >
   <input type="submit">
</form>

<form ...>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" >
   <input type="submit">
</form>

etc...
```

If that's the case, then what you're seeing is expected behavior. When a form is submitted, only the fields contained within the same `<form> ... </form>` tag set will be submitted.